# Python OpenCV - remove title bar, toolbar, and status bar

Tags: python, opencv

I've found documentation regarding C ++, but not much with python.

The basic code to display in python is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To show the image below. But how do I turn this

[image]

To look like this?

[image]

I also want to keep the size. So I've read some people saying to go "full screen". The only way I could think that might work is do "full screen, but then resize it? Not sure if that's a solution either though (also trying to find out how to do that as well... I'm brand new to OpenCV).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a little more looking around:

using these flags is how to do it with QT backend. 
`CV_GUI_NORMAL or CV_GUI_EXPANDED: CV_GUI_NORMAL is the old way to draw the window without statusbar and toolbar, whereas CV_GUI_EXPANDED is a new enhanced GUI.`

unfortunetly, `cv2.namedWindow('image', flags=cv2.CV_GUI_EXPANDED)` does not work, even though I'm pretty sure I have QT backend (actually I'm positive I do).

After looking up `help(cv2)`, I found similar flags `WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED` and `WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL`. So use those.

```
img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg',0)

# Removes toolbar and status bar
cv2.namedWindow('image', flags=cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But still having trouble trying to remove the title bar.

Comment: Did you find a way to remove the title bar?

Comment: I did not. I ended up utilizing tKinter to get the display that I was trying to accomplish and was able to progress with that, so I abandoned looking further into displaying this way.

Answer (score 7):

```js
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2.set(3,320)
cap2.set(4,200)

ret2, image2 = cap2.read()
cv2.imshow('frame2',image2)

cv2.namedWindow('frame2',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty('frame2', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

i have found a trick, just put

```
cv2.namedWindow('frame2',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty('frame2', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

below

```
cv2.imshow('frame2',image2)
```

Here, what we are actualy doing is playing full video in smaller size. That's why there is no title bar and borders.

Comment: This is now outdated.

Comment: @VincentCasey Got some evidence to back that claim up? Some additional details wouldn't hurt either (what version, what HighGUI backend, what exactly is outdated) -- AFAICT full-screen mode is still supported in 4.6.0 with Win32 backend, I just reproduced it.

Comment: @DanMašek It's been a while since I've worked on this but if I can recall it's something with cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN or cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN due to Windows changing something. Like I said though this was a while back and I can't remember exactly what the issue was so take my words with a grain of salt.